# Executing large batch inserts using the SSMS query window

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

Provided nobody/nothing else is accessing the system, is it possible to perform large batch, sequential inserts simply by executing a bunch of INSERTS written into the SQL Query Window, like below?

I tested it on one set of exam and score inserts, and it worked.

```
(1 row affected)
(1 row affected)
```

But I am not sure if it will cause issues executing them all at once in the query window.

Or will this cause problems?

```
--insert exam
INSERT INTO exam.exam (id, title) VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR exam.nextid, 'Myth & Legends');

--insert score using the 'id' above
INSERT INTO exam.scores(examId, baseUrl, assessmentSize, tag)
    SELECT current_value , 
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/school-assessments', 
    101,
    'Myth & Legends' 
    FROM sys.sequences WHERE schema_id = 9

--insert exam
INSERT INTO exam.exam (id, title) VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR exam.nextid, 'Political Abstraction');

--insert score using the 'id' above
INSERT INTO exam.scores(examId, baseUrl, assessmentSize, tag)
    SELECT current_value,
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/school-assessments',
    101, 
   'Political Abstraction'
    FROM sys.sequences WHERE schema_id = 9
```

Comment: No, I don't expect any issues.

Comment: What sort of problems are you concerned about? SSMS is just one of many interfaces to SQL Server.